# Как организовать вектор из стеков на Java?

Tags: структуры, java

Никак не найду в интернете информации.

```
vector <stack<int>> a;
```

Как сделать то же самое в жабе? И как обращаться к n-му стеку, чтобы добавить/убрать/считать элемент?

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь такой конструкцией:

```
Vector<Stack<Integer>> ps = new Vector<Stack<Integer>>();
ps.add(new Stack<Integer>());
ps.get(0).pop();
```

Кроме того, в JavaDoc пишут следующее:

> A more complete and consistent set of
> LIFO stack operations is provided by
> the Deque interface and its
> implementations, which should be used
> in preference to this class. For
> example:
>
> Deque<integer> stack = new
> ArrayDeque<integer>();

Т.е.

```
Vector<ArrayDeque<Integer>> p = new Vector<ArrayDeque<Integer>>();
p.get(index); //получение необходимого вам стека по индексу
```